# How to use the file system plugin with PhoneGapBuild?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use the [file system plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md) with PhoneGap Build. I keep getting cordova.file undefined. What am I missing?

My config.xml file (copy-pasted from a turorial with the gap tag added):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "org.coenraets.employeedirectory"
        versionCode="10"
        version   = "1.1.0">

    <name>Employee Directory</name>

    <description>
        A simple employee directory application
    </description>

    <author href="http://coenraets.org" email="ccoenraets@gmail.com">
        Christophe Coenraets
    </author>

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
</widget>
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script>    
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //cordova.file will be undefined
        alert(cordova.file);
    }

</script>
Cordova?

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
So it seams to be solved when disabling rehydration...

If someone else has problems getting a small PhoneGap Build project up and running, [here](https://github.com/hpssjellis/j20-file-pgb-helloworld) is a repo with a small example that I found usefull.

Comment: version 1.0.1 of the file plugin is quite old. try to remove version from the line : `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />` it should take the latest version automatically.

Comment: Ok! Doesn't solve the problem though. :/

Comment: In your index.html it will be cordova.js and not phonegap.js

Comment: maybe try to specify a older version of phonegap (either in config.xml or in phonegap build page)

Comment: I tried an earlier version. It still din't work and PGB gave the warining "This app isn't using the latest version of PhoneGap. We recommend upgrading to 3.6.3.". (3.6.3 is deafult).

Answer (score 0):

Please check your plugins directory, if it is not there then add it as follows:
`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file`. Also as others mentioned it should be `cordova.js`
[Installation reference](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md#installation)

Comment: Wait what. Do I need this even though I build with PhoneGap Build? :o

Comment: And phonegap.js is interchangable with cordova.js according to the documentation http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_getting_started.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Build

Comment: I added the installation reference to the answer.

Comment: Still when I use PhoneGap Build there shouldn't be a point to install something locally, right? It's even stated in the FAQ http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/support_faq.md.html#FAQ

Comment: If I understand well, that is only referring to PhoneGap itself but not additional plugins. You need to install the plugin to use it.